# bash: /home/user/.bashrc: Permission denied when try to change user from root to user

Tags: linux, bash, centos, su

I'm on centos, when I login as root and use `su x` to change user to `x`, it shows this:

`bash: /home/x/.bashrc: Permission denied`

I try to `source ~/.bashrc` but nothing changes and I also tried following the instructions at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742005/bashrc-permission-denied).

I also can't ssh to user `x`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

actually problem was about /home/* files, they owner of all files had changed due to execution of a wrong shell, so it solved by changing permissions of /home/* with a simple bash script.